# why no colon after location with biber apa?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/joe/MyLibrary.bib}
\author{Joseph Corneli}
\date{9 May 2021}
\title{Mandala: With reference to Open Dialogue}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Joseph Corneli},
 pdftitle={Mandala: With reference to Open Dialogue},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 28.0.50 (Org mode 9.4.5)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\section*{Of course others might see it differently}
\ldots{}and that would be the benefit of approaching these ideas from
within the \emph{Open Dialogue} model of \citet{seikkula2014open}.

\printbibliography[title=Reference]

\end{document}
```

With bibtex item:

```
@book{seikkula2014open,
  title={Open dialogues and anticipations: Respecting otherness in the present moment},
  author={Seikkula, Jaakko and Arnkil, Tom Erik},
  year={2014},
  publisher={National Institute for {Health and Welfare}},
  location={Helsinki, Finland}
}
```

**Output:**

[image: picture of text]

Notice the comma after "Finland" — whereas the APA guidance is “use a colon after the location” (p. 187). (American Psychological Association. (2010). Publication manual of the American Psychological Association (6th ed.). Washington, DC: Author.)

Did the style guidance change...? Or, am I doing something wrong?  Or, is there a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the guidance changed. Current versions of [`biblatex-apa`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) (>= v9.0 released 2019-11-23) implement 7th-edition APA style (from the manual released in 2019).

In 7th-edition APA `@book` entries should not show the location at all. See https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{seikkula2014open,
  title     = {Open dialogues and anticipations:
               Respecting otherness in the present moment},
  author    = {Seikkula, Jaakko and Arnkil, Tom Erik},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {National Institute for {Health and Welfare}},
  location  = {Helsinki, Finland},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{seikkula2014open}.

\printbibliography[title=Reference]
\end{document}
```

[image: Seikkula, J., & Arnkil, T. E. (2014). Open dialogues and anticipations: Respecting otherness in the present moment. National Institute for Health and Welfare.]

If your version of `biblatex-apa` shows the location followed by a comma, you may need to update. I tested with v9.14 (2020-08-28) and got the output shown above.

---

If you want 6th-edition APA style, you need to use [`biblatex-apa6`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6)'s `style=apa6,`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{seikkula2014open,
  title     = {Open dialogues and anticipations:
               Respecting otherness in the present moment},
  author    = {Seikkula, Jaakko and Arnkil, Tom Erik},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {National Institute for {Health and Welfare}},
  location  = {Helsinki, Finland},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{seikkula2014open}.

\printbibliography[title=Reference]
\end{document}
```

[image: Seikkula, J., & Arnkil, T. E. (2014). Open dialogues and anticipations: Respecting otherness in the present moment. Helsinki, Finland: National Institute for Health and Welfare.]

Then you get the location followed by a colon as expected.